# What happens to heap allocated memory when exceptions occur during the constructing 'new' objects?

Tags: c++, memory

What happens to the allocated memory when a class throws an exception during construction and how would you handle something like this.  For example:

```
std::auto_ptr<ThirdPartyClass> au_tpc;

try
{
    au_tpc.reset(new ThirdPartyClass());
}
catch(...)
{
    // What happened to the memory allocated of 
    // sizeof(ThirdPartyClass) for the new instance?
}
```

Comment: You could try to dig this out of the C++ spec.  Or you can spend 5 minutes and just *try it yourself*.  Create a class with a humongous array and a constructor that throws, run this code in a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just works. The memory will be released before your exception handling block is executed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what memory? If the constructor throws, `reset` is never called.

Comment: This is half true only.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Elaborate. I stand by it as completely true.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I can mention additional trivia all day. It doesn't make what I said any less true, and it doesn't make that trivia have any more relevance for this question (in case it's not clear, that article doesn't explain the issue in this question; maybe you could try reading it)

Answer (score 3):

Relevant parts of the C++11 Standard: **5.3.4 [expr.new]**

> **8-** A new-expression obtains storage for the object by calling an allocation function (3.7.4.1). If the new-
>   expression terminates by throwing an exception, it may release storage by calling a deallocation function (3.7.4.2). If the allocated type is a non-array type, the allocation function’s name is `operator new` and
>   the deallocation function’s name is `operator delete`. If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation
>   function’s name is `operator new[]` and the deallocation function’s name is `operator delete[]`.
>
> **18-** If any part of the object initialization described above<sup>76</sup> terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable
>   deallocation function can be found, **the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object
>   was being constructed**, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the new-expression.
>   If no unambiguous matching deallocation function can be found, propagating the exception does not cause
>   the object’s memory to be freed.  [ Note: This is appropriate when the called allocation function does not
>   allocate memory; otherwise, it is likely to result in a memory leak. — end note ]
>
> <sup>76) This may include evaluating a new-initializer and/or calling a constructor.</sup>

In other words, the memory will be freed automatically except under very specific circumstances where the compiler can't find a proper deallocation function (eg. you messed up your custom (de)allocators, or the memory actually doesn't need to be freed).

Answer (score -1):

Check the Item 10 of the Scoot Meyers book 'More Effective C++'.

A important quote from item is:

- "*C++ destroys only fully constructed objects, and an object isn’t fully constructed until its constructor has run to completion.*". So, if you throw an exception in the constructor and dont catch it in the the constructor, the destructor will never be called.

For specific solutions, I strongly suggest you to read this item (or better, the entire book).

Comment: How does this answer the question of what happens with the allocated memory?

Comment: I gave a clue in the class name: ThirdPartyClass.  Something that is third party, typically cannot be tampered with.  That doesn't mean we shouldn't find assurance in what happens when it misbehaves.

Answer (score -2):

> What happens to the allocated memory when a class throws an exception during construction and how would you handle something like this

This is a good question and correct treatment requires a full-blown article. Good news someone wrote that article already: [Constructor Failures](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm).

Comment: This isn't about how constructors work; it's about how `new` works.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes from the question: _What happens to the allocated memory when a class throws an exception during construction_

Comment: I don't care if you prefer to not read the entire thing. It doesn't make this any more helpful.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You assume that the constructor does not allocate memory without having the definition of said constructor.

Comment: The memory is allocated by `operator new`, not the constructor. It's quite clear that `the memory allocated of sizeof(ThirdPartyClass) for the new instance` cannot be anything else.